# Crear carpeta en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**Buenas, estoy tratando de crear una carpeta en la memoria interna para las descargas de mi aplicación. La cosa es que esta carpeta sí se crea pero en la carpeta de instalación, algo así como:

```
sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp.descargas/appdescarga
```

Pero, lo que yo quiero es que se descarguen en el almacenamiento interno o externo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Justo ahí quiero que se cree la carpeta pero no se me ocurre cómo y todo lo que he encontrado ha generado el mismo resultado: crea la carpeta en `sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp.descargas/appdescarga`

Este es mi método para realizar la descarga y crear la carpeta donde se guardará el archivo:

```
public void descargarArchivo(String url, String archivo, Context context){
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription("Este, como tantos otros archivos, se descargan en formato ePub. Recuerda tener una aplicación pertinente para poder leerlo.");

    //Crear la carpeta
    File ruta = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "albumName");

    //vamos a guardar el fichero (opcional). ver tip 5
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(TrantorDetalleLibro.this, String.valueOf(ruta),archivo + ".epub");


    //iniciamos la descarga
    id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

¿Alguien sabe como lograrlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes definir Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ya que indica el directorio de descargas, ùnicamente

```
File ruta = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(), "albumName");
```

De esta forma creara la ruta en

```
Android/data/data/com.myapp.descargas/albumName
```

Comment: Claro, pero eso me crea la carpeta dentro del paquete de mi aplicación. Lo que yo busco es algo como por ejemplo, Whatsapp. Cuando lo instalas, este crea una carpeta dentro del paquete `Android/data/com.whatsapp.suscarpetas` pero, si entras a tu administrador de archivos puedes ver que tienes las carpetas `Android, DCIM, Downloads, Whatsapp` y yo busco algo como eso

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo como whatsapp se puede pero pero en api 29adelante ya no dejan creo mas que seguro ocurra un error en tu app, En api 29 adelante solo te deja en las carpetas de multimedia, pictures,video y otras.  Mas que seguro whastapp en un celular con api 29 creo que es oreo las guardas en otro lado, si tienes un telfono puedes fijarte.

Answer (score 1):

Se que es algo tarde para responder pero [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123812/difference-between-getexternalfilesdir-and-getexternalstoragedirectory) tiene tu respuesta
si tienes tiempo no olvides visitar.

```
getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Devuelve la ruta raíz a su tarjeta SD (por ejemplo , mnt/sdcard/ ). Si guarda datos en esta ruta y desinstala la aplicación, esos datos no se perderán.
Ahora para lo que estas pidiendo seria algo asi:

```
String ubicacion = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
File ruta = new File(ubicacion + "/albumName/");
```

Recuerda utilizar un try/catch si es posible en el momento de crear el directorio, y el manejo de archivos, así puedes capturar las excepciones y errores.