# Como crear un archivo plano en android studio pero en la memoria del dispositivo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, archivo, txt

Estoy intentando generar un archivo plano desde android studio...
https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/liferegisterdiary/FileFolderController.java

La cosa es:

Intentando

```
TRYCATCH
File file = new File("ejemplo.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

No me funciona ... no se que error salta si ya le di permisos?

La cosa es que el unico codigo que me funciono es:

```
public boolean writeFile(String path, String filename, String extension, String text){
        try{
            OutputStreamWriter newFile = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(filename+"."+extension, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            newFile.write(text);
            newFile.flush();
            newFile.close();
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String readFile(String path, String filename){
        try{
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(context.openFileInput(path+filename));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = br.readLine();
            String txt = "";
            while (line != null){
                txt = txt + line + "\n";
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            reader.close();
            return txt;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Esto me funciono perfectamente pero tiene un problema: "Solo se puede aceder dedesde la interface de android studio"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Yo necesito saber como crear un archivo plano que yo pueda aceder desde mi celular??? como creo un archivo plano que pueda ver desde el explorador de archivos de mi celular.**

---

Comment: ¿Cómo es que no sabes que error sale? ¿No revisaste el LogCat? Ese archivo lo vas a ver yendo al package de tu app. Ese archivo si existe en tu dispositivo físico

Comment: Hola, el archivo solo es visible mediante el explorador de archivos del android studio. No es posible verlo desde el telefono o instalando una APP para ver archivos.

Comment: Hola Andres, ya no es permitido crear archivos fuera de la estructura de directorios que se crea para la aplicaciòn, todo debe ser dentro de esta, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas crear un archivo en la memoria interna o externa primeramente debes declarar el siguente permiso en tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y requerir el permiso manualmente.

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

Para **crear una archivo en el almacenamiento interno del dispositivo** debes usar el mètodo **[getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir())**, ejemplo:

```
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"ejemplo.txt");

        if(file.exists()){
            //Existe archivo
        }else{
            try {                    
                //Crea archivo 
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Para **crear una archivo en el almacenamiento externo del dispositivo** debes usar el mètodo **[getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))**, ejemplo:

```
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"ejemplo.txt");

        if(file.exists()){
            //Existe archivo
        }else{
            try {                    
                //Crea archivo 
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Pero de acuerdo a lo que comentas, **es muy importante saber que al compilar desde Android 9 no podemos crear archivos o directorios fuera de la estructura que crea la aplicaciòn**, es decir ùnicamente se pueden crear aquì:

```
Android/data/data/ "package name" /
```

lo mismo para los directorios:

[Crear carpeta en Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392582/crear-carpeta-en-android-studio)