# Error, Archivo no encontrado al abrir un archivo local con startActivity (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy nuevo en Android Studio y estoy haciendo una aplicación WebView que tiene que abrir un archivo pdf almacenado en la memoria interna.
Adjunto mi metodo:

```
public boolean mostrarPDF(String path, Context context) {
    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Carpeta"+path);
    if (pdfFile.exists())
    {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",pdfFile);
        //Uri uri =Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        try
        {
            context.startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No existe una aplicación para abrir el PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "archivo no encontrado! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

en mi manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
... <provider
 android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
 android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
 android:exported="false"
 android:grantUriPermissions="true"
 android:readPermission="${applicationId}.provider.READ">
 <meta-data
   android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
   android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
```

y el xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

pero el lecto que abre me dice que no encuentra el archivo.
alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: ¿Qué te imprime esta línea `(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"Carpeta"+path);``?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Carpeta/mipdf.pdf

Comment: por si se lo preguntaba, uri me asigna content://cl.myproyecto.android.provider/external_files/Carpeta/mipdf.pdf

Comment: Perfecto, entonces, probemos esto: a tu `catch` añade la línea Log.d("TAG", "error: " + e.getMessage()); y coméntame que te imprime esa línea

Comment: no cae en el catch, es como si hiciera todo bien, pero cuando pasa al lector de pdf me dice que no encuentra el archivo

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente el método `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` ya no debe ser usado ya que esta marcado como obsoleto, ahora para obtener la ruta del directorio de almacenamiento externo se debe usar [**getExternalFilesDir()**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/497067/95).

El problema se debe a que ya no podrás acceder a algún archivo que no se encuentre dentro de la estructura:

```
Android/data/data/ <"package name"> /files/
```

ya que al orientar nuestra aplicación a Android 9 (nivel de API 28) o posterior ya no debemos crear o leer archivos o directorios fuera de la estructura que crea la aplicación.

Agrega tu archivo dentro de

```
Android/data/data/ <"package name"> /files/Carpeta/
```

y podrás leerlo de esta forma:

```
 File pdfFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/Carpeta"+archivoPdf);
    if (pdfFile.exists())
    {
      //Existe archivo
      ...
      ...
   } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "archivo no encontrado! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
```